# How to use operator.itemgetter() to sort csv files

Tags: python, csv

I have a set of values in a csv file. The values are shown below.I want those values to be sorted by a layer column, that has values 7208 and 7209 in the example below. Otherwise I want the csv file to be exactly as it is. My code below doesn't seem to sort it correctly.

Here's the csv file:

```
l_d,l_t,utc,SI,UTC,La,Lon,H,layer,N,Pr,EId,Pype,BS,Vo,Te,Chs,PT,Pass
01-08,11:00:19,03:00:19,0x037,01-08_02:58:03,None,None,None,7208,None,None,None,None,87,15.4,None,None,None,MENT 
01-08,11:00:19,03:00:19,0x037,01-08_02:58:03,None,None,None,7209,None,None,None,None,87,15.4,None,None,None,MENT
```

Here's my current code:

```
import sys
import csv
import operator

reader = csv.reader(open("M_B.csv"), delimiter=",")

sortedlist = sorted(reader, key=operator.itemgetter(9), reverse=True)

print(sortedlist)

with open("M_B_Sorted.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(sortedlist)
```

Comment: you want `key=int(operator.itemgetter(8))`

Comment: You need to use `key=lambda row: int(row[8])` plus add code to skip the first row and just copy it from the reader to the writer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the index is wrong. It should be `8`.

And you need to convert the string to `int`; cannot be done solely with `itemgetter`:

```
sortedlist = sorted(reader, key=lambda row: int(row[8]), reverse=True)
```

---

In addition to that, you need to exclude header.

```
import csv

with open("M_B.csv") as fin, open("M_B_Sorted.csv", "wb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter=",")
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    header = next(reader)  # <--- Pop header out
    writer.writerow(header) # <--- Write header
    sortedlist = sorted(reader, key=lambda row: int(row[8]), reverse=True)
    writer.writerows(sortedlist)
```

Comment: I am missing the top row from my output file as well

Comment: @liv2hak, I updated the answer. Please check it out again.

Comment: I need to write only a few columns not all of them. I can do that with header as `writer.writerow(header[0],header[1])`. But this doesn't seem to work for writer.writerows(sortedlist)

Comment: @liv2hak, You need to pass a sequence: For a header: `writer.writerow([[header[0], header[1]])` or `writer.writerow(header[:2])` (if the columns are first two columns)

Comment: @liv2hak, For rows: `writer.writerows(row[:2] for row in sortedlist)`

Comment: it is not necessarily row 0 and row 1.It would be row n, row m, row r etc

Comment: @liv2hak, Then, `writer.writerows([row[0], row[1]] for row in sortedlist)`